# Run a function if opened for the first time in the day

Tags: android, task

I want to run a function whenever user opens the app,
but only once a day, but whenever in the day.

So imagine the user opened the app at 12am and then at 12:10am but the function should run at 12am only and never again until the next day... so how do i check if it is a new day or not ?

Answer (score 0):

You can save the timestamp in shared preferences and check whenever you open the app and update the timestamp if needed

Comment: can you help me with that ?